# using React useEffect to fetch data and controll component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

i am trying to query data using useEffect add those data to state and render them but nothing comes up unless a state in the app changes. this is what i have done so far Please help, Thanks in Advance.

useEffect

```
    // fetchCampaigns
    (async () => {
      dispatch(showTopLoader());

      try {
        const res = await getAgentCampaigns(authToken, "accepted");
        setCampaigns(res.data.campaigns);
        let leads: any[] = [];

        const fetchCampaignLeads = async (id: string) => {
          try {
            const res = await getCampaignLeads(authToken, id);
            return res.data.campaignLeads;
          } catch (error) {}
        };

        // loop through campaigns and get leads
        let resS: any[] = [];
        campaigns.forEach((campaign: any, i: number) => {
          const id = campaign?.Campaign?.id;

          fetchCampaignLeads(id)
            .then((leadsRes) => {
              leads.push(leadsRes[i]);

              if (id === leadsRes[i]?.campaignId)
                return resS.push({
                  ...campaign,
                  leads: leadsRes,
                });

              return (resS = campaigns);
            })
            .catch(() => {})
            .finally(() => {
              console.log(resS);
              setCampaigns(resS);
            });
        });
      } catch (error) {
      } finally {
        dispatch(hideTopLoader());
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

whole component

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import _ from "lodash";
import styles from "../../../styles/CreateLeads.module.css";
import {
  getAgentCampaigns,
  getCampaignLeads,
} from "../../../utils/requests/campaign";
import {
  hideTopLoader,
  showTopLoader,
} from "../../../store/actions/TopLoader/topLoaderActions";
import CampaignSection from "./CampaignSection";
import Empty from "../Empty/Empty";
import SectionHeader from "../SectionHeader/SectionHeader";
import SearchBar from "../SearchBar/SearchBar";
import { RootState } from "../../../store/store";

const CreateLeadsCardsWrapper: React.FC = () => {
  const authToken = useSelector(
    (store: any) => store.authenticationReducer.authToken
  );
  const [stateCampaigns, setStateCampaigns] = React.useState<any[]>([]);

  const [showCampaigns, setShowCampaigns] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [campaigns, setCampaigns] = React.useState<any[]>(stateCampaigns);
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState<string>("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    // Reset filter
    setFilter("");

    let campaignSearch = e.target.value.trim();
    if (campaignSearch.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    let campaignSearchLower = campaignSearch.toLowerCase();
    let campaignSearchUpper = campaignSearch.toUpperCase();
    let campaignSearchSentence =
      campaignSearch.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + campaignSearch.slice(1);

    let results = stateCampaigns.filter(
      ({ leads }: { leads: any[] }, i) =>
        leads &&
        leads?.some(
          (lead: any) =>
            lead.firstName.includes(campaignSearch) ||
            lead.firstName.includes(campaignSearchLower) ||
            lead.firstName.includes(campaignSearchUpper) ||
            lead.firstName.includes(campaignSearchSentence) ||
            lead.lastName.includes(campaignSearch) ||
            lead.lastName.includes(campaignSearchLower) ||
            lead.lastName.includes(campaignSearchUpper) ||
            lead.lastName.includes(campaignSearchSentence) ||
            lead.email.includes(campaignSearch) ||
            lead.email.includes(campaignSearchLower) ||
            lead.email.includes(campaignSearchUpper) ||
            lead.email.includes(campaignSearchSentence) ||
            lead.phoneNo.includes(campaignSearch) ||
            lead.phoneNo.includes(campaignSearchLower) ||
            lead.phoneNo.includes(campaignSearchUpper) ||
            lead.phoneNo.includes(campaignSearchSentence)
        )
    );

    setCampaigns(results);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // fetchCampaigns
    (async () => {
      dispatch(showTopLoader());

      try {
        const res = await getAgentCampaigns(authToken, "accepted");
        setCampaigns(res.data.campaigns);
        let leads: any[] = [];

        const fetchCampaignLeads = async (id: string) => {
          try {
            const res = await getCampaignLeads(authToken, id);
            return res.data.campaignLeads;
          } catch (error) {}
        };

        // loop through campaigns and get leads
        let resS: any[] = [];
        campaigns.forEach((campaign: any, i: number) => {
          const id = campaign?.Campaign?.id;

          fetchCampaignLeads(id)
            .then((leadsRes) => {
              leads.push(leadsRes[i]);

              if (id === leadsRes[i]?.campaignId)
                return resS.push({
                  ...campaign,
                  leads: leadsRes,
                });

              return (resS = campaigns);
            })
            .catch(() => {})
            .finally(() => {
              console.log(resS);
              setCampaigns(resS);
            });
        });
      } catch (error) {
      } finally {
        dispatch(hideTopLoader());
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setCampaigns(stateCampaigns);
    campaigns.length > 0 && setShowCampaigns(true);
    console.log(showCampaigns);

    dispatch(hideTopLoader());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.wrappers}>
      {/* Multi step form select a campaign first then fill info on the next step */}
      <SectionHeader text="Campaign Leads" />
      {showCampaigns && stateCampaigns.length === 0 && (
        <>
          <Empty description="No agents yet" />
          <p>Join a campaign.</p>
        </>
      )}
      {showCampaigns && stateCampaigns.length > 0 && (
        <>
          <p className="text-grey-500">Create Leads for Campaigns.</p>

          <section className={styles.container}>
            <SearchBar
              placeholder="Find Campaign Leads"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            {campaigns.map((item: any) => (
              <CampaignSection
                key={item?.Campaign?.id}
                id={item?.Campaign?.id}
                name={item?.Campaign?.name}
                imageUrl={item?.Campaign?.iconUrl}
                campaignType={item?.Campaign?.type}
                productType={item?.Campaign?.Products[0]?.type}
              />
            ))}
          </section>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateLeadsCardsWrapper;
```

Comment: Can you create a sandbox with you code so I can help you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are two things wrong in yoour code :
1- you should not have two useeffects with the same dependencies in your case: [] you have to merge those useeffects into one or change the second one's dependencies

2- doing async code in useeffect can be problematic sometimes. it is better to create an async function which does the query to the backend and sets the state and the call the function in your useeffect like below :

```
const getData = async()=>{
// do some queries and set the state

}

React.useeffect(()=>{
   getData()
},[])
```

Comment: You're wrong. It's complete;y fine to use useEffects with the same variables as dependencies!

Comment: yes its fine and I did not say it wouldn't work. but if they update the same state, or one of them update a state and the other uses that data, they would interfere and cause weird behaviors occasionally. that is why I said it's wrong. It was better to say you might make mistakes while doing so.